# KineticJS: image.destroy() doesn't destroy the Kinetic.Image and group.destroy() causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am facing for the last few days a very strange problem with KineticJS and my Web-Application:

In general my application consists of several "pages" which are represented by `Kinetic.Group`s. All of the groups except one are offset, which means not visible. The non-visible groups are all added to a separate `Kinetic.Layer` temporarily (for caching etc...) and the only visible page is added to another `Kinetic.Layer` to make it interactive.

All of the pages (or `Kinetic.Group`s) are stored in an array (because there is no fixed amount) and are accessed like the following: `activelayer.add(pages[1]);`.

Everything fine so far, but when I'm trying to destroy a `Kinetic.Shape` like an image, it doesn't destroy the image, which means it is still there, visible and interactive. In the next step I wanted to destroy the entire "temporary" `Kinetic.Layer`, which resulted in a infinite loop and caused my browser to crash.

So far I've investigated the `destroy`-function of KineticJS and found out, that `go._removeID(this.getId());` and `go._removeName(this.getName(), this.getId());` functions receive only `undefined` values.

Destroying layers, which are unrelated to the pages mentioned above, works without any problems.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you draw the layer after destroying the object? That's a common mistake that makes it "seem" like nothing is happening. Also, did you set a name and or ID for the items that you are destroying? That might be why they are undefined..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the layer is redrawn after destroying the object and no, I did not set any name and or ID, but that shouldn't be a problem because of the KineticJS-internal `_id` of every object which is used to "find" the right shape while destroying it. Also, if I destroy a shape, KineticJS returns the object, which should have a `undefined` value as it has been destroyed. In my case it returns the shape with all its properties like the `destroy`-process has never been performed.

Comment: My next guess is that your Kinetic.Shapes are not being stored into your activeLayer array properly. Have you tried destroying a shape by accessing it's **ID** directly? Do you get the same results? How are you referencing your Kinetic Objects to be destroyed?

Comment: Hopefully you've chased your retained references down by now, but if not, we'll need some code to make any real analysis.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have time to check the retained references, but as soon I get to it, I'll let you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may have added a layer multiple times.